# What chapter of the manga does Snow White with the Red Hair anime leave off at?

Tags: snow-white-with-the-red-hair

I wanted to read the manga because I really like this anime. It’s one of the best romance anime I’ve watch.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mangaupdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=16482),

> Season 1 ended at **Vol. 4 Chapter 17** while Season 2 ended at **Vol. 8 Chapter 32** with an alternate ending.

Since Season 2 has an alternate ending, it might be best to start where Season 1 ended.